# Angular says is not a known Element but shared module is being imported

Tags: angular

Using the latest Angular

I've put together a module for sharing components, because doing many of them and repeating them all over the application is a waste and can't be maintained.

What I want is:

```
  DataPaneNgComponent

           |

ComponentCommonModule

  |             |
Dashboard    Customers
```

**Dashboard** and **Customers** are their own module/component with HTML (front views) that need to use **DataPaneNgComponent** which should be a reusable component.

So what I do is declare **DataPaneNgComponent** in **ComponentCommonModule** and add it to both export and declaration. Now I expect anyone importing **ComponentCommonModule** to find the component.

I then added **ComponentCommonModule**  as an import to both **Dashboard** and **Customers**. They're both almost identical modules (I copied Customers from Dashboard and removed some unneeded extra components), then added it to every single location on the app where it needed to (routing, etc)

The problem is, when I run the Angular server, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/pages/customers/customers.component.html:3:7 - error NG8001: 'ngx-data-pane-ng' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngx-data-pane-ng' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-data-pane-ng' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

3       <ngx-data-pane-ng title="Title1" iconName="fa-file-invoice-dollar" numVal=3 dynPipe="DecimalPipe"></ngx-data-pane-ng>
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/pages/customers/customers.component.ts:14:16
    14   templateUrl: './customers.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CustomersComponent.
src/app/pages/customers/customers.component.html:7:7 - error NG8001: 'ngx-data-pane-ng' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngx-data-pane-ng' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-data-pane-ng' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

7       <ngx-data-pane-ng title="Title2" iconName="fa-dollar-sign" numVal=1022133 dynPipe="CurrencyPipe"></ngx-data-pane-ng>
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/pages/customers/customers.component.ts:14:16
    14   templateUrl: './customers.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CustomersComponent.
```

So what's happening is that the code is failing only in Customer module, but Dashboard is happy.

If I comment out the html that calls the ngx-data-pane-ng tag, it builds without errors.

They both have the same code as far as the import is concerned.

When I ran the whole project again, I saw:

```
WARNING in E:\frontend\src\app\pages\customers\customers.component.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.
```

Now, the server runs and the code displays the shared component. But the compilation gives this errors.

I've already been through a lot of posts that say that the issue is that the shared module needs to export the shared component, and that the other two modules just need to import the shared module (not the component). But I've already done that.

Shared model code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NbThemeService } from '@nebular/theme';
import { takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { SolarData } from '../../@core/data/solar';
import {
  NbButtonModule,
  NbCardModule,
  NbProgressBarModule,
  NbTabsetModule,
  NbUserModule,
  NbIconModule,
  NbSelectModule,
  NbListModule,
} from '@nebular/theme';
import { NgxEchartsModule } from 'ngx-echarts';
import { NgxChartsModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';
import { ThemeModule } from '../../@theme/theme.module';
import { PercentPipe, CurrencyPipe, DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

import { DataPaneNgComponent } from './data-pane-ng/data-pane-ng.component'

import { DynamicPipe } from './dynamic.pipe'


@NgModule({  
  imports: [
    ThemeModule,
    NbCardModule,
    NbUserModule,
    NbButtonModule,
    NbIconModule,
    NbTabsetModule,
    NbSelectModule,
    NbListModule,
    NbProgressBarModule,
    NgxEchartsModule,
    NgxChartsModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    DataPaneNgComponent,
    DynamicPipe,
  ],
  exports: [
    DataPaneNgComponent,
    DynamicPipe,
  ]
})
export class ComponentCommonModule { }
```

**Customers Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
  NbButtonModule,
  NbCardModule,
  NbProgressBarModule,
  NbTabsetModule,
  NbUserModule,
  NbIconModule,
  NbSelectModule,
  NbListModule,
} from '@nebular/theme';
import { NgxEchartsModule } from 'ngx-echarts';
import { NgxChartsModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';

import { ThemeModule } from '../../@theme/theme.module';
import { CustomersComponent } from './Customers.component';


import { ComponentCommonModule } from '../components/component-common.module';
import { PercentPipe, CurrencyPipe, DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ThemeModule,
    NbCardModule,
    NbUserModule,
    NbButtonModule,
    NbIconModule,
    NbTabsetModule,
    NbSelectModule,
    NbListModule,
    NbProgressBarModule,
    NgxEchartsModule,
    NgxChartsModule,
    ComponentCommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    CustomersComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    PercentPipe,
    CurrencyPipe,
    DecimalPipe,
  ],
})
export class CustomersModule { }
```

**Dashboard Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
  NbButtonModule,
  NbCardModule,
  NbProgressBarModule,
  NbTabsetModule,
  NbUserModule,
  NbIconModule,
  NbSelectModule,
  NbListModule,
} from '@nebular/theme';
import { NgxEchartsModule } from 'ngx-echarts';
import { NgxChartsModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';

import { ThemeModule } from '../../@theme/theme.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { ProfitCardComponent } from './profit-card/profit-card.component';
import { DashboardChartsPanelComponent } from './charts-panel/charts-panel.component';
import { OrdersChartComponent } from './charts-panel/charts/orders-chart.component';
import { ProfitChartComponent } from './charts-panel/charts/profit-chart.component';
import { ChartPanelHeaderComponent } from './charts-panel/chart-panel-header/chart-panel-header.component';
import { ChartPanelSummaryComponent } from './charts-panel/chart-panel-summary/chart-panel-summary.component';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-chartjs';
import { StatsCardBackComponent } from './profit-card/back-side/stats-card-back.component';
import { StatsAreaChartComponent } from './profit-card/back-side/stats-area-chart.component';
import { StatsBarAnimationChartComponent } from './profit-card/front-side/stats-bar-animation-chart.component';
import { StatsCardFrontComponent } from './profit-card/front-side/stats-card-front.component';
import { TrafficRevealCardComponent } from './traffic-reveal-card/traffic-reveal-card.component';
import { TrafficBarComponent } from './traffic-reveal-card/front-side/traffic-bar/traffic-bar.component';
import { TrafficFrontCardComponent } from './traffic-reveal-card/front-side/traffic-front-card.component';
import { TrafficCardsHeaderComponent } from './traffic-reveal-card/traffic-cards-header/traffic-cards-header.component';
import { TrafficBackCardComponent } from './traffic-reveal-card/back-side/traffic-back-card.component';
import { TrafficBarChartComponent } from './traffic-reveal-card/back-side/traffic-bar-chart.component';
import { SolarComponent } from './solar/solar.component';
import { DataPaneComponent } from './data-pane/data-pane.component';
import {
  DashboardVisitorsAnalyticsComponent,
} from './visitors-analytics/visitors-analytics.component';
import {
  DashboardVisitorsAnalyticsChartComponent,
} from './visitors-analytics/visitors-analytics-chart/visitors-analytics-chart.component';
import {
  DashboardVisitorsStatisticsComponent,
} from './visitors-analytics/visitors-statistics/visitors-statistics.component';
import { DashboardLegendChartComponent } from './legend-chart/legend-chart.component';
import { DashboardUserActivityComponent } from './user-activity/user-activity.component';
import { DashboardProgressSectionComponent } from './progress-section/progress-section.component';
import { SlideOutComponent } from './slide-out/slide-out.component';

import { CountryOrdersComponent } from './country-orders/country-orders.component';
import { CountryOrdersMapComponent } from './country-orders/map/country-orders-map.component';
import { CountryOrdersMapService } from './country-orders/map/country-orders-map.service';
import { LeafletModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet';
import { CountryOrdersChartComponent } from './country-orders/chart/country-orders-chart.component';
import { EarningCardComponent } from './earning-card/earning-card.component';
import { EarningCardBackComponent } from './earning-card/back-side/earning-card-back.component';
import { EarningPieChartComponent } from './earning-card/back-side/earning-pie-chart.component';
import { EarningCardFrontComponent } from './earning-card/front-side/earning-card-front.component';
import { EarningLiveUpdateChartComponent } from './earning-card/front-side/earning-live-update-chart.component';

import { ComponentCommonModule } from '../components/component-common.module';
import { PercentPipe, CurrencyPipe, DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ThemeModule,
    NbCardModule,
    NbUserModule,
    NbButtonModule,
    NbIconModule,
    NbTabsetModule,
    NbSelectModule,
    NbListModule,
    ChartModule,
    NbProgressBarModule,
    NgxEchartsModule,
    NgxChartsModule,
    LeafletModule,
    ComponentCommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent,
    StatsCardFrontComponent,
    StatsAreaChartComponent,
    StatsBarAnimationChartComponent,
    ProfitCardComponent,
    DashboardChartsPanelComponent,
    ChartPanelHeaderComponent,
    ChartPanelSummaryComponent,
    OrdersChartComponent,
    ProfitChartComponent,
    StatsCardBackComponent,
    TrafficRevealCardComponent,
    TrafficBarChartComponent,
    TrafficFrontCardComponent,
    TrafficBackCardComponent,
    TrafficBarComponent,
    TrafficCardsHeaderComponent,
    CountryOrdersComponent,
    CountryOrdersMapComponent,
    CountryOrdersChartComponent,
    DashboardVisitorsAnalyticsComponent,
    DashboardVisitorsAnalyticsChartComponent,
    DashboardVisitorsStatisticsComponent,
    DashboardLegendChartComponent,
    DashboardUserActivityComponent,
    DashboardProgressSectionComponent,
    SlideOutComponent,
    EarningCardComponent,
    EarningCardFrontComponent,
    EarningCardBackComponent,
    EarningPieChartComponent,
    EarningLiveUpdateChartComponent,
    SolarComponent,
    DataPaneComponent,

  ],
  providers: [
    CountryOrdersMapService,
    PercentPipe,
    CurrencyPipe,
    DecimalPipe,
  ],
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

Comment: Please add your shared module code

Comment: Added code for shared component. As you can see, it adds the data-pane-ng component.

Comment: did u tried restarting ng serve? Actually I cant find any error in shared.module.... Add ur customer module code

Comment: I am using Visual studio Ode and the NPM script it has. I restarted it. and it re-ran ng serve. Still gives the same error

Comment: Pls add dashboard module code

Comment: I've added that code too

Comment: Sorry I went through all the code thrice nearly. But I am not able to find the issue.. I can only help through anydesk if needed...

Comment: Show your component? And are your module lazy loaded? Also, you gave an import from `'./Customers.component'` with a capital C. Maybe that's the reason for the warning?

Comment: David, that seems to have been it. I found that there was uppercase in the import and it looks like this was causing the error. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to add an answer as in the ./Customers.component being uppercase, I'd happily set it as the answer

Comment: Better to close it as a typo :)

Comment: How to do that?